# Powershell gets stuck creating a registry key

Tags: powershell, registry

I tried to create a new registry key using powershell

```
PS HKCU:\> New-Item -Path .\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\ -Name TEST -Value TEST
```

But somehow the process doesn't return I have to manually exit with CTRL+C
When I browse the key with regedit I see it was created, but why does the console not finish the command ?
Did anyone ever have a similar problem?

Comment: You need to provide a proper registry path like `HKCU:\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts` or use `Set-Location HKCU:` first. Then, a Key only has a Name. (a key's **property** also has a value).

Comment: Sorry, i did not mention it, but I'm already in the Location HKCU:

Comment: But as i said, the code works as expected, the registry key is created, also the key's property has the right value. The problem is that the New-Item command does never finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, Your code does not work because you need to either provide a proper registry path like

```
HKCU:\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts
```

OR use `Set-Location HKCU:` first, so the New-Item cmdlet will know where to create something new.

A registry **Key** does not have a value, only registry entries (properties) do.
So in order to create a new key with name "TEST", and create a new entry in that new key, use two lines of code:

```
New-Item -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts' -Name 'TEST'
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\TEST' -Name 'Test' -Value 'Just Testing'
```

You can also do this in one single statement using .NET [SetValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue?view=net-5.0)

<sup>Sets the name/value pair on the specified registry key, using the specified registry data type. If the specified key does not exist, it is created.</sup>

```
[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\TEST", "Test", "Just Testing", 1)
```

The last parameter (in this case `1`) is the [RegistryValueKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind?view=net-5.0) you want to set. (in this example a String)

Comment: As I said the command worked, as it created the registry key with the key-value pair with correct name and value. Only problem is that the command does never end. Powershell just halts and does not return

Comment: But I tried using the .Net method and it works too, it creates the key and finishes. Maybe this is some kind of powershell bug

Comment: Didn't work for me. The first line gives an error. "New-Item : The registry key at the specified path does not exist"